# How do you modify a WordPress theme class with a child theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using a theme called "views base." Documentation is here: http://wp-types.com/documentation/views-inside/views-base-theme/views-base-customization/

I've created a child theme and I'm trying to figure out how to add a new widget area to the theme.

The parent theme's functions.php file has this line:
    require_once('class_base_theme.php');

This file contains a class called "class_base_theme" with a $sidebar_array property with an array of all the widget regions.

I can easily add in a new region in this parent class simply by adding it to the $sidebar_array property. But I can't figure out how to extend and modify this class in the child theme. I can't do it in my child theme's functions.php file because it is called before the parent's functions.php file.

Comment: I was able to accomplish what I needed to by copying over the class_base_theme.php file into my child theme and then did a require_once('class_base_theme.php') in my child theme's functions.php file.

Is there a better way to do this, though?

Comment: I would like to know the answer to this one too, anyone know the best/correct way to do it  ?

Comment: Actually, it depends on the parent theme. If the parent uses `if (!class_exists('class_name'))` before loading the class, then it'll work, but if not you're going to get an error trying to redeclare a class. I would suggest extending the class. Make a new php file in your theme, require it, then extend the parent's class that way like `Child_Class extends Parent_Class {}`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it depends on the parent theme. If the parent uses if `(!class_exists('class_name'))` before loading the class, then it'll work, but if not you're going to get an error trying to redeclare a class. I would suggest extending the class. Make a new php file in your theme, require it, then extend the parent's class that way like `Child_Class extends Parent_Class {}`

Now, from within your new class `Child_Class` you should be able to access $sidebar_array and do whatever you want with it, as well as use the parent's class functions, if needed.